# Command Line Interface Ruby

Tags: ruby

Say I have the code:

```
print(">>> ")
command = gets
```

What I want to do, is execute the `command` variable as one would normally do in Ruby, by putting backticks around the code you want to execute. How would I do this? If I do:

```
`command`
```

it just tries to execute the word command. How do I execute the variable???

Comment: Be very careful doing this. Allowing a user to enter a command, then executing it for them, allows them to execute the command with the permissions your code runs under. If it runs as root, and the user enters "`rm -rf /`", your system will go bye-bye really fast.

Comment: yep i know! I'm obviously not gonna release this to other people, I just got the idea from the book Metaprogramming Ruby. About a page after, it told me how bad of an idea it was haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just interpolate it like you would with a string:

```
`#{command}`
```

Comment: +1 You can guess things like this in Ruby and surprisingly often it just works.